# Where download sun.* Java source?

Tags: java, java-6, sun

I am supporting a project that uses Java 6 and need to go deep into the Java source (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection to be precise). However src.zip attached in Java JDK folder does not contain source code for sun.* packages. Is it possible to download the source code I need and if yes - where from?

Comment: You can find the code using google.  For example google for "java.lang.String source", and you will get a link to grepcode.com.  Or google for "openjdk 1.6 source code" and you will get a page for downloading the source.

Comment: I know grepcode.com. It gives single files an not whole packages. Or I have  overlooked a way to download whole package there?

Comment: Reread my comment.  Sorry, but finding the Java source code using google is not exactly rocket science.  And such questions are explicitly off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Did not know this code belongs to OpenJDK. I have downloaded "openjdk 1.6 source code" but did not find what I need in there just by a quick search. I would need to do "make" if want to get sources? Anyways @Viacheslav Shalamov answers gave me what I needed almost right away

Comment: Ah, found it in jdk\src\share\classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the specific `sun.*` class?
How about grepcode?
http://grepcode.com/search?query=sun.*

You can also find the `sun.*` code in the jdk sources and download it here:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/a0ea2ba34bdd/src/share/classes/com/sun

(I've put a link to jdk6 for you, but you can find any version there, of course)